# Knowing what grammar is used

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

> Starting a position in a company that I had no real background in

Is this a correct sentence?
Could somebody help me extract the grammar out of it like what is the noun here, adjective, adverb, verb, etc...
**My Attempt:**
in -> Preposition
a -> article
I -> Noun
real -> Noun
background -> Noun
position -> Noun
Company -> Noun
had -> Verb (I checked this online, not sure why this is a verb)

Comment: It's not a valid sentence (the only finite verb is in a subordinate clause).

Comment: Putting the preposition at the end is very common in informal speech. "a position ... I had no background *in*".  In formal register it would be "a position *in which* I had no background".  Compare: "The veterinarian we took our dog to is retiring." vs "The veterinarian to whom we took our dog is retiring."

Comment: Sorry pensee, we don't do proofreading on this site, nor do we fully break down the grammatical structure of random words, so I've closed this question.

Comment: This is incorrectly closed, it's a request to tag a sentence, not to improve or correct it.

Comment: @BadZen Sounds like a good discussion to bring up on [our Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/). I'm not aware of any prior discussions there about this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Laurel, I've added an ot/ot question there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a grammatically correct sentence, it is a fragment. It does not have a subject or a main verb.

Here are some modifications that have *subjects* and **main verbs**:

- *I* **was starting** a position in a company that I had no real background in.
- *Starting a position* in a company that I had no real background in **made** me nervous.

### Parts of Speech

Starting a position in a company that I had no real background in

**Nouns**

- Position
- Company
- Background

**Verbs**

- Starting (depends on the grammar of the sentence. This could either be a participle (verb) or a gerund (noun) See [this article](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/ing-forms/#:%7E:text=A%20verb%20ending%20in%20%2Ding,their%20functions%20in%20a%20sentence.) for more information.)
- had - *To have* is the basic form of this verb. Had is the past tense of have. It means "Owned" or "possessed" so "I had two dogs" means "I owned two dogs in the past."

**Pronouns**

- I
- That

**Adjectives / Adverbs**

- Real
- No

**Prepositions**

- In
- In (the second time)

**Articles**

- A
- A (the second time)